# Understanding SqlMapper.ICustomQueryParameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper, table-valued-parameters

What's the point of `DataTable.AsTableValuedParameter` method which returns a `SqlMapper.ICustomQueryParameter` when having to pass a datatable as TVP to DB using Dapper?

I could send TVPs to DB just as normal datatable and execute queries just fine. I am not sure what performing `AsTableValuedParameter` on it buys additionally.

For e.g. this works:

```
int rowsAffected = await conn.ExecuteAsync(
    "MyProc",
    new
    {
        myVar = (DataTable)GetThatDataTable(),
    },
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Also, an additional question, what is the need for `typeName` optional parameter in `AsTableValuedParameter` method? Works fine without it too.

Comment: I might be really obtuse, but what is `c`? You're showing a method executed on an object but it's not clear (at least to me) what that object is.

Comment: Sometimes people like myself explore and learn something we don't already know so that we can answer questions. We learn something new and help other people at the same time. The question should really specify on what class the method is called.

Comment: @ScottHannen oops I am sorry. It is a connection object, some `IDbConnection`. `ExecuteAsync` is an extension method on `IDbConnection` from Dapper's side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine in your case because you are using a stored procedure; the user-defined type needs to come from *somewhere*, and in the case of stored procedures: that somewhere can be the declared parameter type.

However, dapper also works with ad-hoc `CommandText` queries. In that case, without this call: there *is no type name*, and the call will fail. It is important to me that features support `CommandText` usage too, since that is a very common use-case.

If it works fine for you without: do that!

Comment: Fair enough. So is the point of `AsTableValuedParameter` just to give a type name? In other words, what would be the difference between passing a `System.Data.DataTable` and `ICustomQueryParameter` implementation ? Looking at the source I couldn't find a use for latter (looks like a wrapper around DataTable).

Comment: @newfal the only extra thing it *needs to work* is: a UDF type name... so: yes?

Answer (score 3):

Passing a SQL Server table valued parameter requires a type name, so it's not optional. It has to come from somewhere.

`SqlMapper` has an extension method that sets the type name for a `DataTable` in its `ExtendedProperties`. If you don't specify the type name in the `AsTableValuedParameter` method, it checks `ExtendedProperties` for the type name.

So the type name is still getting specified, just not in the method where you're looking. It's probably happening in the method that creates and returns the `DataTable`. Look for use of `public static void SetTypeName(this DataTable table, string typeName)`.

[`SqlMapper` source](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/071a3fd5a0e9a3ebb9b598737b94b49c56446722/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs), line 3672.

That's convenient because if a given `DataTable` type exists only to be used to pass as a table valued parameter then it makes sense that you should be able to associate it with the type of that parameter. That makes it easier to identify which schema the `DataTable` must conform to.

Comment: *Passing a SQL Server table valued parameter requires a type name, so it's not optional.*

Not sure. One, even if I dont specify a type name the DB operation works. It doesn't if I pass a wrong Type name. It should be either empty (or null) or match the exact type. Two, even if I pass a DataTable (not `icustomqueryparameter`) with no type name anywhere executions passes.

Comment: Not sure how reliable [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26203140/661933) is, but the poster says TypeName is required only for parameterized sql, not TVPs.